# Switch to root user within bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Im currently logged in as **admin** and I want to edit the **/etc/hosts** file which required **root** access.

I'm not able to make the changes. The script gets executed sucessfully but the changes arent made.

**My Script - Runs Sucessfully when executed from terminal**

```
sudo -s
echo "127.0.0.1" >> /etc/hosts
su admin
```

> sudo -s - switches to root without password when executed from terminal
>
> su admin - switches back to  admin user when run on terminal

**My /etc/hosts file remains empty after running the script**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to actually switch your user within the script. 
Also, you can't `echo` something as root like that because the redirect (`>>`) is executed by the shell.

A possible workaround is using `tee`:

```sh
echo "127.0.0.1" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

Further explanation:

`tee` basically takes the data from the standard input and writes it either to the standard output, or to a file. For more information see the commands manual ($ `man tee`)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. can you please explain what does tee do? I'm new to linux environment.

Comment: @HackersInside Glad I could help! :) See my edit for an explanation